# How to perform case condition in the multiple JOIN statement with different table in Red shift?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am stuck with implementing the below requirement.kindly please help me to fix this query

**The requirement**

The condition needs to be implemented in theory

Need to populate data for market_num in "demo" table from either "table1" or "table2" table based on "source_country_palce" column  in "demo" table. 
It shall be picked from "table1" if present there else need to pick from "table2".I am stuck with writing the condition.Kindly please help me to fix this

**Query tried so for**

**condition 1**

```
select distinct b.market_num
from test.demo a
    join test.table1 b on a.source_country_palce = b.market_palce
where b.market_num >=1
```

**condition 2**

```
select distinct b.market_num
from test.demo a
    join test.table2 b on a.source_country_palce = b.country_palce
where b.market_num >=1
```

But I am stuck with implementing the above condition like when the 1st condition fails then I need to pick "market_num" from the second condition

Answer (score 1):

My pure guess:

```
select distinct coalesce(b.market_num,c.market_num )
from test.demo a left outer join test.table1 b 
on a.source_country_palce=b.market_palce
left outer join test.table2 c
on a.source_country_palce=c.country_palce
where b.market_num >=1 or c.market_num >=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(b.market_num, c.market_num)
FROM test.demo a
LEFT JOIN test.table1 b ON a.source_country_palce = b.market_palce
    AND b.market_num >= 1
LEFT JOIN test.table2 c ON a.source_country_palce = d.country_palce
    AND b.market_num < 1
    AND c.market_num >= 1
```

I put your conditions in the join in a way that it will only match if the second join if it fails the first one.